# Rails action not found for controller when saving web forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been doing a rails tutorial (on lynda) and I've been working on a simple cms. It has a controller and model for Subjects and I can save a subject using the rails console without a problem. But when I try to make a new subject using a web form, I get this error: `The action '#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x2166e28>' could not be found for SubjectsController`. 
The Subject model has a single relationship (`has_many: pages`) but that should not be affecting this because there are no foreign keys which the webform is saving.

The controller methods for new and create look like this:

```
def new
    @subject = Subject.new
end

def create
    #Instantiate a new object using form params
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])

    #Save the object
    if @subject.save

        #If save succeds, redirect to list action
        redirect_to(action: list)
    else

        #If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
        render('new')
    end
end
```

Something important: the controller successfully saves the new subject. It just produces this error instead of redirecting

The View for the web form looks like this:

```
<html>
    <%=  link_to("<< Back to List", {action:'list'}, class: 'back-link')%>

    <div class="subject new">
        <h2>Create Subject</h2>

        <%= form_for(:subject, url: {action: 'create'}) do |f|%>

        <table summary="Subject form fields">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Visible</th>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="form-buttons">
            <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: please post the code of your view which has the form on it

Comment: There. I've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be redirecting to `:list` instead of `list`, or better

```
redirect_to(action: 'list')
```